# Tidycal embed content disappears after navigating to another page Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js14

Tidycal embed content disappears after navigating to another page in Next.js
consider this simple code:

```
rafec
...
return (
<>
<Script src='https://asset-tidycal.b-cdn.net/js/embed.js'></Script>
<div className='tidycal-embed' data-path='*****/consultation-paypal' title='hellowolrd'>
</div>
</>
)
}
```

When the page is loaded for the first time, the embed content is displayed, but after navigating to another page and coming back, the content is no longer there.
I already tried to inject the script with a useEffect and remove it on component unmount but it has no effect on the result.
Thank you for your help !